# Why isn't the node I added to the end of my linkedlist printing out?

Tags: python, linked-list, append, nodes

Why isn't the node I added to the end of my linkedlist printing out? I added a new node with 8 as the data inside it and it append but its not printing out. When I run this code, it prints: 1,2,3 instead of 1,2,3,8.
Please help I am new to Python

```
#creation of nodes and list
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    # looping through list
    def print_list(self):
        dummy = list.head
        while dummy.next != None:
            print (dummy.data)
            dummy = dummy.next

    def append(self,data):
        newnode = Node(data)
        dummy = list.head
        while dummy.next != None:
            dummy = dummy.next
        dummy.next = newnode
        #print(newnode.data)

node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)
node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3

list = LinkedList()
list.head = node1
list.append(8)

#list.print_list()
list.print_list()
```

If I run 'node3.next.data' I get '8' but then why doesn't it print 8 at the end when I print the whole list?

Comment: `print_list()` doesn't print the last node because `dummy.next` is `None` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in `print_list()` only prints the value when `dummy.next != None`. But that condition isn't true for the last node.

Change the condition of the loop to test the current node, not the next node.

```
def print_list(self):
    dummy = list.head
    while dummy:
        print (dummy.data)
        dummy = dummy.next
```